# Asp.net The compiler failed with error code 128. but only on remote server

Tags: asp.net, server, publish

when I launch my application on **VS2013** in debug or release mode everything is fine. But when I publish it on the remote server I get this error:
`Server Error in '/Doratletica' Application`.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** The compiler failed with **error** code 128.

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>
>   "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library
>   /utf8output
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
>   /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\doratletica\2d4f66e3\5486bc0d\assembly\dl3\879ef36c\188ffd17_b4b2d001\Doratletica.DLL"
>   /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\doratletica\2d4f66e3\5486bc0d\assembly\dl3\06d2e9d7\049e0f50_6fa3d001\EO.Web.DLL"
>   /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\doratletica\2d4f66e3\5486bc0d\assembly\dl3\ec623854\c6891b50_6fa3d001\System.Data.SQLite.DLL"
>   /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\doratletica\2d4f66e3\5486bc0d\assembly\dl3\5784996f\fc40ef17_b4b2d001\App_global.asax.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /out:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\doratletica\2d4f66e3\5486bc0d\App_Web_site.master.cdcab7d2.eoeflm-m.dll"
>   /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /warnaserror- 
>   "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\doratletica\2d4f66e3\5486bc0d\App_Web_site.master.cdcab7d2.eoeflm-m.0.cs"
>   "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\doratletica\2d4f66e3\5486bc0d\App_Web_site.master.cdcab7d2.eoeflm-m.1.cs"

I've found other people with the same problem but not only on the remote server and in any case no solution worked.
I've also tried to precompile my solution but it didn't work.

tthanx in advance for any help

Comment: check: http://forums.iis.net/t/1159648.aspx?Compiler+Error+Message+The+compiler+failed+with+error+code+128+ and this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCompilerError128AndMicrosoftSupport.aspx

Comment: OK I guess we were all right. The problem was solved automatically by the hosting site I use (aspspider.info). I guess they noticed and solved the problem since: 1. many other people posted the same problem in the forum. 2. they added the section Web site:
If you are experiencing un resolvable errors with your website here, you may try to Repair site.
If that does not work, you may close your web site and re create a new site under a different domain.
If you just want to update your site details, you may edit the site title and description here.